# slowAES not working with CBC/PKCS7 - alternatives?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

Basically, how can I encrypt in javascript in CBC/PKCS7 so I can decrypt in php or .NET?

I've tried slowAES but the cyphered output text doesn't seem to be correct.

I've compared slowAES and .NET encryption and given the same byte array inputs (key, iv and message) to both, slowAES returns a different byte array output.

I've also compared results with .NET and php's mcrypt and they produce the same output.

I've tried this fix [link text](http://code.google.com/p/slowaes/issues/detail?id=5) but it didn't work.

So, assuming is a slowAES problem, is there a working alternative, or does anybody know how to fix it?

oh, and I can encrypt and decrypt if I only use slowAES :x

---

**Update** with an example:

**javascript encryption:**

```
var bytesToEncrypt = cryptoHelpers.convertStringToByteArray("2|2010-11-23+10:04:53|0");
// [50, 124, 50, 48, 49, 48, 45, 49, 49, 45, 50, 51, 43, 49, 48, 58, 48, 52, 58, 53, 51, 124, 48]

var key = cryptoHelpers.base64.decode("de1310982b646af063e7314e8ddd4787");
//[117, 237, 119, 215, 79, 124, 217, 190, 184, 233, 167, 244, 235, 119, 187, 223, 94, 30, 241, 215, 93, 227, 191, 59]

var iv = cryptoHelpers.base64.decode("v/VCTAlV5+kexBFN16WY5A==");
//[191, 245, 66, 76, 9, 85, 231, 233, 30, 196, 17, 77, 215, 165, 152, 228]

var result = slowAES.encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, 
slowAES.modeOfOperation.CBC,
key,
slowAES.aes.keySize.SIZE_128,
iv);

return result['cipher'];
//[114, 176, 211, 189, 47, 133, 36, 115, 173, 19, 122, 45, 30, 212, 189, 54, 149, 167, 92, 127, 198, 13, 121, 102, 70, 172, 119, 194, 249, 98, 107, 236]
```

**.NET/Silverlight** encryption:

```
    class AES
    {
        AesManaged aes;

        public AES(string base64key, string base64IV) 
            : this(Convert.FromBase64String(base64key),Convert.FromBase64String(base64IV)) 
        {}

        public AES(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            // CBC/128/PKCS7
            aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;
        }
        public string Encrypt(string strInptData)
        {
            byte[] utfdata = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strInptData);

            PrintByteArray(utfdata);
// [50, 124, 50, 48, 49, 48, 45, 49, 49, 45, 50, 51, 43, 49, 48, 58, 48, 52, 58, 53, 51, 124, 48]

            PrintByteArray(aes.Key);
// [117, 237, 119, 215, 79, 124, 217, 190, 184, 233, 167, 244, 235, 119, 187, 223, 94, 30, 241, 215, 93, 227, 191, 59]

            PrintByteArray(aes.IV);
// [191, 245, 66, 76, 9, 85, 231, 233, 30, 196, 17, 77, 215, 165, 152, 228]

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            csEncrypt.Write(utfdata, 0, utfdata.Length);
            csEncrypt.Flush();
            csEncrypt.Close();

            // Showing our encrypted content
            byte[] encryptBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();

            PrintByteArray(encryptBytes);
// [89, 116, 38, 217, 71, 199, 73, 174, 55, 139, 158, 231, 22, 238, 252, 245, 147, 206, 176, 157, 1, 141, 88, 178, 160, 112, 135, 182, 13, 200, 53, 121]

            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptBytes));
        }
    }

string base64key = "de1310982b646af063e7314e8ddd4787";
string base64iv = "v/VCTAlV5+kexBFN16WY5A==";

aes = new AES(base64key, base64iv);

auth_token = aes.Encrypt("2|2010-11-23+10:04:53|0");
```

As you can see .NET and javascript produce different byte arrays, so is not even a base64/url-encode/decode thingy..

Comment: So how do you transfer the key to JavaScript?  I hope thats over https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your secret key is 24 bytes (192 bits) long, but you're claiming it's only 16 bytes (128 bits) long:

```
var result = slowAES.encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, 
slowAES.modeOfOperation.CBC,
key,
slowAES.aes.keySize.SIZE_128, // <- Here is your problem
iv);
```

By changing `SIZE_128` to `SIZE_192`, it should work. I wrote a Java program that emits the same output your JavaScript example produced.